# Translate influx percentile function to promQL

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I need to translate the following influx query to promQL

```
SELECT PERCENTILE(value,95) FROM db WHERE cat = 'time' AND metricName = 'CPU Time' AND time > now() - 1h GROUP BY server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following [MetricsQL query](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html):

```
histogram_quantile(0.95,
  sum(
    histogram_over_time(
      db_value{cat="time",metric_name="CPU Time",server=~"s1|s2"}[1h]
    )
  ) by (vmrange,server)
)
```